# is it possible to preload links tht a dynamically loaded to a page?

Tags: php, jquery, image-processing, preload

Is it possible to preload images from a link. a thumbnail gallery in which the the thumbnails are linked to their respective large images using php. is it possible to use a jquery code to preload the large images even though they are just links?

```
<?php  
   error_reporting(0);
/* function:  returns files from dir */
function get_files($images_dir,$exts = array('jpeg','gif','png','jpg')) {
$files = array();
if($handle = opendir($images_dir)) {
while(false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
  $extension = strtolower(get_file_extension($file));
  if($extension && in_array($extension,$exts)) {
    $files[] = $file;
  }
}
closedir($handle);
}
return $files;
}

/* function:  returns a file's extension */
function get_file_extension($file_name) {
return substr(strrchr($file_name,'.'),1);
}

$images_dir = 'hftpnyc/thumbs/';
$thumbs_dir = 'hftpnyc/thumbs/thumbnails/';
$thumbs_width = 100;
$images_per_row = 11;
$string = "";
/** generate photo gallery **/
$image_files = get_files($images_dir);
if(count($image_files)) {
$index = 0;
foreach($image_files as $index=>$file) {
$index++;
$thumbnail_image = $thumbs_dir.$file;
//if(!file_exists($thumbnail_image)) {
  //$extension = get_file_extension($thumbnail_image);
  //if($extension) {
    //make_thumb($images_dir.$file,$thumbnail_image,$thumbs_width);
  //}

//}

error_reporting(0);

echo '<div class="smllpic" style=" padding: 0px; margin: 0px; border: 1px solid black; display: block; width: 100px; height:100px; float: left; "><a href="'.$images_dir.$file.'" rel="lrgimg" class="lightbox"> <img id="thumbs" src="',$thumbnail_image,'" width="100px"/></a></div>';

if($index % $images_per_row == 0) { echo '<div class="clear"></div>'; }
}
}

else {
echo '<p>There are no images in this gallery.</p>';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try a Google search for "[jQuery image preload](https://www.google.com/#hl=en&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=jquery+image+preload)"? Yeah, almost 500,000 results chock full of useful plugins and tutorials.

Here is a sampling:

[jQuery Image Preload Plugin](http://www.farinspace.com/jquery-image-preload-plugin/)

[jQuery Smart Preloader Plugin](http://www.egrappler.com/jquery-image-preload-plugin-smart-preloader/)

[jQuery Preload Images - Tutorial and Example](http://ditio.net/2010/02/14/jquery-preload-images-tutorial-and-example/)